# How to concatenate strings from two arrays?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

This is what I have

```
NSMutableArray Code = [COMM 112, MATH 101, SCI 201];
NSMutableArray Name = [Commerce, Calculas , Science];

NSMutableArray Course;
for(int i=0; i < [code count]; i++)
{
    [Course objectAtIndex:i] = [Code objectAtIndex:i] + "-" + [Name objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

What I want to end up with:

```
Course = [COMM 112 - Commerce, MATH 101 - Calculas, SCI 201 - Science];
```

This is just pseudo code! Any help to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * courseCodes = [@"COMM 112", @"MATH 101", @"SCI 201"];
NSMutableArray * courseNames = [@"Commerce", @"Calculus" , @"Science"];

// Check: if ([courseCodes count] != [courseNames count]) something went wrong...   

NSMutableArray * courseDescriptions = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i < [courseCodes count]; i++)
{
    NSString * courseDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",
                                    [courseCodes objectAtIndex:i],
                                    [courseNames objectAtIndex:i]];
    [courseDescriptions addObject:courseDescription];
}
```